# unable to upload a file in php

Tags: php, file, upload

i tried a lot but yet can't get the solution please help me out as i'm unable to upload my file code is shown below :

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("PSD", "JPG", "JPEG", "GIF", "PNG", "AI", "ZIP", "RAR", "PDF", "DOC", "DOCX", "XLS", "XLSX", "PPT");
    $extension = pathinfo( $_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000) && array_search($extension, $allowedExts)!==false) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br/>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            if (file_exists("uploaded_files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "common/uploaded_files" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "common/uploaded_files" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }

    ?>
```

below is my php form code :

```
<input type ="file" name= "file" id ="file"/>
```

Comment: Do your form has `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`?

Comment: yes it's dere on my form but still i'm getting error invalid file

Comment: it means your if condition is not working, are you uploading a large file `>200000`

Comment: yes it's dere on my form but still i'm getting error invalid file

Comment: no i'm not uploading a file size larger than 200000

Comment: your $allowedExts are all in caps so it may cause your if condition to fail.

Comment: Some Tips:
1) While checking file extension, upper case to extension and then compare.
2) print the `$_FILES` to check whether file is being uploaded.
3) Check if the provided upload path is writable by web server.

Comment: thanks you in advance @pupil but its show error while refreshing the page even before the file is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for your reference..

```
$filename = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_dir = "../../file/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {       
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        echo "</br>The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your allowedExts does not match lowercase, try this small modification.

```
$extension = strtoupper(pathinfo( $_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```